# query date range in MongoDB from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date-range

I am trying to get all the users within the specified date range, 
My database structure looks like this:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("58b545d4b57eeb2cc456248a"),
    "attendance" : [ 
        {
            "2017-03-16" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"],
            "2017-03-17" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"],
            "2017-03-18" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"],
            "2017-03-19" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"],
            "2017-03-20" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634","58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81635"]
        }, 
        {
            "2017-03-17" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"],
            "2017-03-18" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"],
            "2017-03-19" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"],
            "2017-03-20" : ["58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634","58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81635"]
        }
    ]
    .......
}
```

and to query it:

```
routes.find({_id: ObjectId("58b545d4b57eeb2cc456248a"), $or:[{'attendance[0]' : {$gte: '2017-03-17' }}, {'attendance[1]': {$gte: '2017-03-17'}}]})
```

but it is not fetching any results.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your dates are being held in the *keys* (fieldnames); but MongoDB is only designed to query on data being held in the field *values*. I suggest you restructure your data to something like this:

```json
{
    _id : ObjectId("58b545d4b57eeb2cc456248a"),
    "attendance" : [ 
        {
            "dateitems" : [
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-16"), "who" : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634")]},
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-17"), "who" : : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634")]},
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-18"), "who" : : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634")]},
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-19"), "who" : : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634")]},
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-20"), "who" : : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634"),ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81635")]}
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "dateitems" : [
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-17"), "who" : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634")]},
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-18"), "who" : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634")]},
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-19"), "who" : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634")]},
                {"when" : ISODate("2017-03-20"), "who" : [ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81634",ObjectId("58c108b9ebd9ae24dca81635")]}
            }
        }
    ]
    .......
}
```

With this kind of data structure, you can query to get the output you need, for example like this:

```js
routes.aggregate([
    {$match: { _id: ObjectId("58b545d4b57eeb2cc456248a")}},
    {$match: {"attendance.dateitems.when" : {$gt: ISODate("2017-03-17")}}}
})
```

Here are some of the key points I've changed in my restructuring:

1. Instead of strings, every ObjectId reference is in a true [ObjectID type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#objectid); this will allow effective comparisons and lookups.
2. Instead of strings, every date is in a standardised [Date data type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date) using the ISODate format; this will allow effective comparisons such as $gt.
3. The attendance data has been expanded into an array of *dateitem* objects, each of which has a field for the date and a field for the referenced objects (I'm guessing those are the ids of people attending); that way, each data value is stored as a [field value](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/#document-database) - not as a fieldname.

Comment: thanks for the valuable input, can you please help me out how am I supposed to edit the current database and save it in the new format, since am new to this

Comment: @warl0ck That's a big question, and not possible to answer reliably without knowing how your database is created and maintained. If it is under the control of a single application, then one sensible approach might be to define a data migration process to transform the existing data into the new format. However, you will also need to alter your application's database commands, so as to store new data in the new format.

Comment: Yes, I know i will have to change the data format of how it is saved and the model as well, in the nodejs template, but how to change so that i can search date range. PS: I have all the access.

Comment: From nodejs I get ReferenceError: ISODate is not defined

Answer (score 0):

**In node.js we can query ISODate by new Date() to find date range data**

```
db.collectionName.find({ 
   'updatedAt': {
          $gte: new Date('2019-04-19T14:16:04.065Z'),
          $lte: new Date('2019-04-19T14:16:04.070Z')
        }})
```